# Find the angle $\Phi$ for an orbit close to a circle of radius $r$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

There is an odd identity I cannot figure out in the titular exercise from V. I. Arnold's book on mechanics. He claims in an answer to the exercise (page 37) that:
\begin{align} 
\frac{M}{r^2\sqrt{V''(r)}} = \sqrt{\frac{U'}{3U'+rU''}}
\end{align}
when $V(r)=U(r)+\frac{M^2}{2r^2}$. This possibly involves a change of variables $x=M/r.$

I've tried to prove this but have no leads. I figure it might have something to do with the form he claims U has, although part of this chain of exercises is to find what $U$ can be. My numerical tests of the claim fail too so I must be missing something.

Comment: This might be better asked on physics.SE. If you do want to ask it here, you're going to need to include the equations that you want to derive this from, since many people here won't be familiar with them.

Comment: I still strongly suspect this is a basic property of the forms written above. $r, x$ are variables, $M$ is a constant, differentiation is with respect to the variable the function is written in terms of.

Comment: I cannot find better than $$\sqrt{U’-V’\over 3(U’-V’)+rU’’}$$

Comment: @enthdegree: That can't be, since if you add a linear term to $U$ (and thus to $V$), you change the right-hand side but not the left. Note that this is not true for the form derived by marwalix above, so this may be an error in the statement of the identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{M}{r^2\sqrt{V''(r)}} = \sqrt{\frac{U'}{3U'+rU''}}$$
$$\frac{M^2}{r^4V''(r)} = \frac{U'}{3U'+rU''}$$
$$\frac{r^4}{M^2}V''(r)=3+r\frac{U''}{U'}$$
Squaring might introduce additional solutions. At end of this calculus one must check and keep only the valid solutions.
$$V(r)=U(r)+\frac{M^2}{2r^2}$$
$$V''(r)=U''(r)+\frac{3M^2}{r^4}$$
$$\frac{r^4}{M^2}(U''(r)+\frac{3M^2}{r^4})=3+r\frac{U''}{U'}$$
$$(\frac{r^4}{M^2}-r\frac{1}{U'})U''(r)=0$$
First set of solutions , from $U''(r)=0$ :
$$\boxed{\begin{cases}
U(r)=c_1r+c_2\\ 
V(r)=c_1r+c_2+\frac{M^2}{2r^2}
\end{cases}}$$
Second set of solutions, from $\frac{r^4}{M^2}-r\frac{1}{U'}=0\quad\implies\quad U'=\frac{M^2}{r^3}$
$$\begin{cases}
U(r)=-\frac{M^2}{2r^2}+c_3\\ 
V(r)=-\frac{M^2}{2r^2}+c_3+\frac{M^2}{2r^2}=c_3
\end{cases}\quad\text{rejected because}\quad \begin{cases}
V''(r)=0\\
3U'+rU''=0
\end{cases}$$
The original ODE becomes $\quad\frac{M}{r^2\sqrt{0}} = \sqrt{\frac{U'}{0}}=\infty$

This is the conclusion in a mathematical sense. Nevertheless one should check whether the solution $\quad \begin{cases}
U(r)=-\frac{M^2}{2r^2}+c_3\\ 
V(r)=c_3
\end{cases}\quad$ has a physical meaning.

Comment: You can get proper parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adapt to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @jorikt. Thanks for your interest and comment. I know very well how to addapt the size of delimiters. Nevertheless if you are pleased to improve the typing it is up to you in using the "edit" button. You are wellcome.

Comment: This is not really an answer, as the equation in question is not a differential equation but an equation between derivatives in one (extremal) point.

Answer (score 1):

First one has to remark that the question, while connected to the differential equation of the motion under a central force field, is not itself a differential equation but the relation between Taylor coefficients of the expansion of two potential functions.

### Central force field

$\newcommand{\fx}{{\mathfrak{x}}}\newcommand{\pd}{\partial}\newcommand{\D}{{\mathit\Delta}}$

The section that this exercise is from is about the motion in the plane under a central force field
$$
\ddot\fx=-\frac{\pd U(|\fx|)}{\pd \fx}.\tag1
$$
Due to the rotational symmetry of this situation, the angular momentum is a conserved quantity, first integral, constant of motion.
After fixing the angular momentum (here $M$ instead of the more usual $L$)
$$M=r^2\dot \phi,\tag2$$
where $(r,\phi)$ are the polar coordinates of the plane point $\fx=(x,y)$, the dynamic for the radius is independent of the angle, it is
$$
\ddot r=-V'(r)\text{ where }V(r)=\frac{M^2}{2r^2}+U(r).\tag3
$$

With that as back-story, compute the derivatives of $V$
\begin{align}
V'(r) &= -\frac{M^2}{r^3}+U'(r)\tag{4a}
\\
V''(r) &= \frac{3M^2}{r^4}+U''(r)\tag{4b}
\end{align}

### Perturbation of a circular orbit

> The **exercise** in question now asks to find the angle $\Phi$ between pericenter and apocenter *for an orbit close to a circular orbit* of radius $r^*$ (and the same angular momentum).

Previously it was explained that the radius of such a circular orbit is at a (regular) minimum of $V$, so that $V'(r^*)=0$, $V''(r^*)>0$. The perturbed orbit has an energy $$\frac12\dot r^2+V(r)=E=V(r^*)+\D E$$ so that at the extremal points with $\dot r=0$ one gets in the Taylor expansions around $r^*$ the equation $$V(r^*)+\D E=V(r^*+ \D r)=V(r^*)+\tfrac12 V''(r^*)(\D r)^2+O((\D r)^3).$$ Simplifying and solving for the increment gives $$r_{\max},r_{\min}\approx r^*\pm\D r$$ with $$\D r=\sqrt{\frac{2\D E}{V''(r^*)}}. $$

### Half-period

By the previous exercise, the half-period is computed as
\begin{align}
\Phi&=\int_{r_{\min}}^{r_{\max}}\frac{M/r^2}{\sqrt{2(E-V(r))}}dr\tag{5a}
\\
&\approx\int_{r_{\min}}^{r_{\max}}\frac{M/r^2}{\sqrt{2(\D E-\frac12V''(r^*)(r-r^*)^2)}}dr
\\
&=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{M/(r^*+s\D r)^2}{\sqrt{V''(r^*)}\sqrt{1-s^2}}ds
=\frac{M/(r^*)^2}{\sqrt{V''(r^*)}} \int_{-1}^{1}\frac1{\sqrt{1-s^2}}ds+O((\D r)^2)
\\
&\approx\Phi_{\rm cir}=\pi\frac{M/(r^*)^2}{\sqrt{V''(r^*)}}\tag{5b}
\end{align}
Now use $V'(r^*)=0\implies U'(r^*)=\frac{M^2}{(r^*)^3}$ to eliminate the auxiliary variables $M$ and $V$ from this formula (not completely, as $r^*$ depends on $M$) to get
$$
V''(r^*)=\frac{3}{r^*}U'(r^*)+U''(r^*)
\\
\frac{M}{(r^*)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{U'(r^*)}{r^*}}
\\
\implies
\Phi_{\rm cir}=\pi\frac{M/(r^*)^2}{\sqrt{V''(r^*)}}=\pi\sqrt{\frac{U'(r^*)}{3U'(r^*)+r^*U''(r^*)}}.\tag6
$$

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer, I should've put more context for how it came up.

Comment: May I ask why $\Delta r=\sqrt{\frac{2\Delta E}{V''(r*)}}$?

Comment: @DashengWang : The energy is $E=\frac{m}2\dot r^2+V(r)$. In the extremal positions $r_\pm$ of the oscillation of $r$ one has $\dot r=0$, so $E=V(r^*)+ΔE=V(r_\pm)=V(r^*)+0+\frac12V''(r^*)(r_\pm-r^*)^2+...$ Now take the quadratic approximation and compute the solutions for $r$ or $\pmΔr=r_\pm-r^*$.