# How to solve the ODE for unstable circular orbits?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, general-relativity

I'm reading Wald's book and on page 139 there is an ODE which I can't solve.
$$\frac{1}{2}\dot{r}^2 + \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)\left(\frac{L^2}{r^2}+K\right) = \frac{1}{2}E^2$$
$$L = r^2 \dot{\phi}$$
I know that K = 1.
For stable orbits it's really easy, we just make $\dot{r} = 0$.
But what happens if it's unstable? Is there any code available to plot this?

Comment: What is $\dot{\phi}$? Is it constant?

Comment: Concentrate on the first equation, because the second just fixes the evolution of the angle coordinate $\phi$ of your particle. Then by general theorem you can prove existence and uniqueness of solutions $r(t)$ for finite time parameters $t$. I would not expect this equation to have a clsed form solution - are you searching for that? Be clearer about "what happens"? Do you want existence or an explicit/numerical solution?

Comment: All circular orbits have $\dot r=0$, i.e., constant radius. What you have to find out is what happens if the initial values $r_0, E$ get perturbed a little. Do you get small, bounded, oscillations around the circiular orbit, or an ever more diverging behavior.

Comment: @LutzLehmann You are absolutely right. We can still invoke Peano, but after different rewriting...

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3514316/find-the-angle-phi-for-an-orbit-close-to-a-circle-of-radius-r for an extended discussion of this topic based on the book of V.I.Arnol'd on classical mechanics.

Comment: @Ian $\dot{\phi} = \frac{d\phi}{d\tau}$ but I'm focusing on the first equation only. On page 140 it says that $L^2 > 12M^2$.

Comment: @ThomasPreu I'm not the best at coding tbh. I just want the numerical solution for the ODE combining these two equations and plot the orbits. I want to compare the Newtonian mechanics and general relativity.

Comment: @JohnMayer OK. You want numerical solutions. It would be nice, if your question would state this explicitly - I am thinking of future readers of your question here. Which tools are at your disposal. Matlab? To get a first impression ($M=1,L=4,K=1,E=1$): [use WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+for+r%3A+%28D%5Br%5Bt%5D%2Ct%5D%29%5E2%2B%281-2*1%2Fr%5Bt%5D%29*%284%5E2%2Fr%5Bt%5D%5E2%2B1%29-1%5E2%3D0%2C+r%5B0%5D%3D6)

Comment: @ThomasPreu I have Matlab and Scilab but I prefer Matlab.

Comment: @ThomasPreu "It would be nice, if your question would state this explicitly - I am thinking of future readers of your question here." You are right I will change it soon.

Answer (score 0):

To get a circular orbit of radius $r^*$ in the dynamic to
$$
\frac12\dot r^2+V_L(r)=\frac12E^2,
$$
or as kinetic equation
$$
\ddot r+{V_L}'(r)=0,
$$
one needs that $r^*$ be a stationary value of $V_L$, ${V_L}'(r^*)=0$. This binds $r^*$ and $L$ (even if not always uniquely). The stability property is then determined by the sign of ${V_L}''(r^*)$, for stability $r^*$ has to be a strict minimizer of $V_L$.

---

One possible next step is to parametrize $r(t)=1/u(\phi(t))$ which results in $\dot r=Lu'$. The potential for the dynamic in $u$ is then polynomial
$$
L^2\frac12u'^2+\frac12(1-2Mu)(L^2u^2+K)=\frac12E^2.
$$
The derivative of the potential is
$$
P_L'(u)=-M(L^2u^2+K)+(1-2Mu)L^2u=-3ML^2u^2+L^2u-MK\\
=-\frac{L^2}{12M}(6Mu-1)^2+\frac{L^2}{12M}-MK
$$
with real roots for $L^2>12M^2K$ at
$$
U_\pm=\frac{L\pm\sqrt{L^2-12KM^2}}{6ML}
$$
As the parabola of the derivative is open below, the second derivative at the smaller root is positive, at the larger negative. The smaller $U_-$ corresponds to the larger $R_+=1/U_-$, so that indeed the circular orbit at $R_+$ is stable, as long as $R_+$ exists as real solution.

---

This parametrization also leads directly to a solution of the plotting problem, the second order equation is
$$
0=u''(ϕ)+P_L'(u(ϕ))=u''-3ML^2u^2+L^2u-MK
$$
This can be solved for $ϕ\in[0,n·2\pi]$, then plotted as real and imaginary part of $e^{iϕ}/u(ϕ)$. The corresponding times can be obtained from the solution of the coupled equation $t'(ϕ)=1/(Lu(ϕ)^2)$.

Comment: I just want a numerical solution for the ODE and plot the orbits.

Comment: What exactly is it you want to plot? For perturbations that are relevant to stability discussions the differences in the orbits are invisible for long times. If you take larger differences in initial conditions it becomes hard to say if that are still perturbations or simply different orbits.

Comment: I need a code where I can plot stable and not stable orbits. First of all I want to plot the orbit of Mercury around the Sun. I want to solve the ODE $\frac{1}{2}\dot{r} + \frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{2M}{r})(\frac{L^2}{r^2}+K) = \frac{1}{2}E^2$ numerically and combine it with $L = r^2\dot{\phi}$ by using a while loop. Is there a way to use the angle instead of time like 6-8 $\pi$? Secondly I want to plot the orbit of a spaceship around a BH (stable orbit) and show the time dilation (proper time). It doesn't have to be a long time instead 3-4 orbits. I have all the data in geometrizedunits

Comment: For a stable orbit it's really easy. For $L^2 > 12M^2$, the stable orbits ($\dot{r} = 0$) exist at the radius $r = R_+$. Where $R_+ = \frac{L^2+\sqrt{L^4-12L^2M^2}}{2M}$. I'm just struggling with solving the ODE, coding and plotting.